# In django 1.11, how can I render form using formset_factory

Tags: python, django

I have started leaning Django1.11 a few days ago, but I can't understand how can I render form using formset_factory.

Here is myproject/app/views.py file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ArticleFormSet

def get_name(request):
    form = ArticleFormSet()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form' : form})
```

Here is app/forms.py file.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import formset_factory

class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    pub_date = forms.DateField()

def ArticleFormSet(self):
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)
```

Here is name.html file.

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have tried to render form on the browser, but exception has occurred like this.

> ArticleFormSet() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a function for formset_factory. Remove the `ArticleFormSet` function and only this line is enough.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import formset_factory

class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    pub_date = forms.DateField()

ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Simon. When I remove the ArticleFormSet function, the browser renders form. But I wanna know the reason why I have to remove the function. Why doesn't browser render the form, when I declare the function.

Comment: @YuiryKozlenko I guess you don't have to declare this formset inside that class and it won't work.

Comment: I will tell you why

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: See whenever we wanted to pass the form to template we just invoke the form and assign to one variable called in this case `form = ArticleForm()` But in our case formset. We extracted and created formset out of `ArticleForm`

Comment: So we wanted to do like `ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)`

Comment: But I have declared ArticleFormSet function out of the ArticleForm class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145326/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-yuiry-kozlenko).